# separate a csv file into separate folders

Tags: csv, batch-file, export, names

I have an access database that marks quite a few records for export to a CSV file.  The customer requires a CSV file for electronic upload to their billing system.  However, EACH, record must have it's own CSV folder.  Each folder must be names with the ticket number and date of the record.

I would like to export all records marked for export to the CSV in a batch.  Then, programmatically  move through the records and move each ticket to the separate CSV file...with the unique name.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped and have been working on this/searching the internet for months.

Comment: Too generic a question. Do you want to develop this in access? What have you tried so far? You seem to know what to do - so what is keeping you? Do not expect someone to provide you with this code out of the blue. Perhaps instead of researching just start and post any errors you might get stuck with

Comment: My FOSS program csvfix can do the splitting and file naming, but not the folder creation - see http://code.google.com/p/csvfix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it all in Access, you don't need to do it in two steps, you can create a file from each row in a loop.